# Radio button value in php not working properly

Tags: php, radio-button

I'm having this strange issue that's been bothering me for a few days now. There is a form with six groups of three radio buttons. There are thee values in each group, "slabije", "bolje" and "odlicno".
When I start the form with the value of "slabije" in any of the groups and then check other five buttons everything works just fine. The problem is when I start the form with with values of "bolje" or "odlicno", in any of the groups, I am not getting any values. Can anyone help me solve this. Thank you very much.

```
<form action="" method="post">
   <div class="pristup"> <label for="">prilazni put</label> </div>
  <div class="pristup-radio">
    slabije<input value="slabije" class="radio" type="radio" name="prilazni_put">
   bolje <input value="bolje" class="radio" type="radio" name="prilazni_put">
   odlicno <input value="odlicno" class="radio" type="radio" name="prilazni_put">
    </div>
   <div class="pristup"> <label for="">teren</label> </div>
  <div class="pristup-radio">
   slabije <input value="slabije" class="radio" type="radio" name="teren">
   bolje <input value="bolje" class="radio" type="radio" name="teren">
   odlicno <input value="odlicno" class="radio" type="radio" name="teren">
    </div>
   <div class="pristup"> <label for="">polozaj</label> </div>
  <div class="pristup-radio">
   slabije <input value="slabije" class="radio" type="radio" name="polozaj">
   bolje <input value="bolje" class="radio" type="radio" name="polozaj">
    odlicno<input value="odlicno" class="radio" type="radio" name="polozaj">
    </div>
   <div class="pristup"> <label for="">gabariti</label> </div>
  <div class="pristup-radio">
    slabije<input value="slabije" class="radio" type="radio" name="gabariti">
   bolje <input value="bolje" class="radio" type="radio" name="gabariti">
    odlicno<input value="odlicno" class="radio" type="radio" name="gabariti">
    </div>
   <div class="pristup"> <label for="">infrastruktura</label> </div>
  <div class="pristup-radio">
    slabije<input value="slabije" class="radio" type="radio" name="infra">
   bolje <input value="bolje" class="radio" type="radio" name="infra">
    odlicno<input value="odlicno" class="radio" type="radio" name="infra">
    </div>
   <div class="pristup"> <label for="">vrsta</label> </div>
  <div class="pristup-radio">
    slabije<input value="slabije" class="radio" type="radio" name="vrsta">
   bolje <input value="bolje" class="radio" type="radio" name="vrsta">
    odlicno<input value="odlicno" class="radio" type="radio" name="vrsta">
    </div>
    kvadrati
    <input type="text" name="kvadrati">
    <button name="button" type="submit">Izracunaj</button>

</form>
```

PHP

```
if(isset($_POST['button'])){
$kvadrati = $_POST['kvadrati'];
$prilaz = $_POST['prilazni_put'];
$teren = $_POST['teren'];
$polozaj = $_POST['polozaj'];
$gabariti = $_POST['gabariti'];
$infra = $_POST['infra'];
$vrsta = $_POST['vrsta'];

if($prilaz == "slabije")
{
$prilaz_izracun = -0.04;
}
 if($prilaz == "bolje")
{
$prilaz_izracun = 0.04;
}
if($prilaz == "odlicno")
{
$prilaz_izracun = 0.04;
}
if($teren == "slabije")
{
$teren_izracun = -0.04;
}
if($teren == "bolje")
{
$teren_izracun = 0.04;
}
if($teren == "odlicno")
{
$teren_izracun = 0.04;
}
 if($polozaj == "slabije")
{
$polozaj_izracun = -0.4;
}
if($polozaj == "bolje")
{
$polozaj_izracun = 0.4;
}
if($polozaj == "odlicno")
{
$polozaj_izracun = 0.4;
}
if($gabariti == "slabije")
{
$gabariti_izracun = -0.1;
}
if($gabariti == "bolje")
{
$gabariti_izracun = 0.1;
}
if($gabariti == "odlicno")
{
$gabariti_izracun = 0.1;
}
if($infra == "slabije")
{
$infra_izracun = -0.25;
}
if($infra == "bolje")
{
$infra_izracun = 0.25;
}
if($infra == "odlicno")
{
$infra_izracun = 0.25;
}

if($vrsta == "slabije")
{
$vrsta_izracun = -0.17;
}
if($vrsta == "bolje")
{
$vrsta_izracun = 0.17;
}
if($vrsta == "odlicno")
{
$vrsta_izracun = 0.17;
}
```

Comment: What does _" I am not getting any values"_ mean? And what does $_POST contain in that case?

Comment: It means that I'm not getting anything, When form is submitted there as logic to calculate the given values, and it works fine but only if value of "losije" is the first one. Any other combination doesn't work. When I echo values it work, but only in the afore mentioned conditions.

Comment: To make it more clear, buttons in english are rated poor, good, excellent. When the form starts with all poor or poor and any other combo, it works fine. But when it starts with good or excellent, nothing happnes. It looks like that the $_POST doesn't contain anything.

Comment: It looks like or _does_ `$_POST` contain nothing? what does debugging show?

Comment: Sory for late answer. I've checked and re-checked the code, and debugged it, no errors are given.

Comment: Solved it. Curly bracket was missing.